# How to make the input field progress bar full width as in 100% of parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Friend of mine helped me with this progress bar. It's working absolutely fine except that the progress bar  isn't full width of the parent div. The new width after each input is entered is added via JS in px. I'm new to javascript so need help.

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/greysniper/fnkpu5gc/

I have tried converting it to percentage but have been unsuccessful yet. The initial width is 11px whereas the new width after each input tag is filled is also in px.

```
<div>
  <span class='meter' style="display:inline-block;background:yellow;color:green;width:0;height:20px"></span>
  <span class='perc'>0</span>%
</div>
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="dont-track" style="background-color: blue;">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="dont-track" style="background-color: blue;">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<input class="dont-track" style="background-color: blue;">
<input class="track">
<input class="track">
<select class="track">
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

$('.track').change(function(e) {
  update_progress();
});

function update_progress() {
  var count = $('.track').length;
  var length = $('.track').filter(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).length;
  var done = Math.floor(length * (100 / count));
  $('.perc').text(done);
  $('.meter').width(done);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line in your function `update_progress` to:

```
$('.meter').width(done + '%');
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answer. Such a silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using pixels instead of percent
Instead of 25%, you are setting the width to 25px

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.meter').width(done);
```

has to be

```
 $('.meter').width(done+"%");
```